# What's the difference between emptying the trash and securely emptying the trash?

Tags: macos, trash

The `trash` command has these two options:

```
-e  Empty the trash (asks for confirmation)
-s  Securely empty the trash (asks for confirmation)
```

What's the difference?

Comment: `-bash: trash: command not found`. What kind of command is this, where did you install it from? Did you reach out to the author of it for clarification?

Comment: @nohillside turns out it's a `brew install trash` one, i forgot that

Comment: I think since El Cap you can only get to Secure Empty Trash in a spinny rust HD, not an SSD… as there's no way to ensure secure delete on an unencrypted SSD.

Comment: Anyway, closely related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132982/whats-the-difference-between-empty-trash-and-secure-empty-trash?rq=1. And kind of irrelevant nowadays as the functionality is not part of recent versions of macOS any longer.

Comment: Ah, https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash then. Which just calls Finder to empty the trash (see trash.m, line 224).